# Android : overridePendingTransition at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-activity, transition

I'm trying to slide two activities at the same time, but the 1st activity slide before the 2nd, **showing a little empty black space**.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, myClass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    //finish activity
    finish();
    //transition
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000"
android:fromXDelta="100%" 
android:toXDelta="0%">
</translate>
```

slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000"
android:fromXDelta="0%" 
android:toXDelta="-100%">
</translate>
```

How to start the animations at the same time please ? thanks you.

Comment: you can decrease the time of first activity

Comment: it's not the desired effect, and it's still the same problem, we can see a little empty black space for arround 100ms, then the 2nd layers clip to the first, and the animation run